# Use BeanUtils for Setting setter value

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

I try to set value using setter but null comes.Please help me with this and give if some other better way is there to do.

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class TestSetter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        BeanUtils.setProperty(t,"te","teval");
        System.out.println("tevalue :"+t.getTe());
    }
}
class Test
{
    String te;

    public String getTe() {
        return te;
    }

    public void setTe(String te) {
        this.te = te;
    }

}
```

**Exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: Cannot set te
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:313)
    at test.reflection.TestSetter.main(TestSetter.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'te' has no setter method
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1746)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1022)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Not my area of experience, but try `BeanUtils.setProperty(t,"Te","teval")` instead...

Comment: sorry due thats also gives same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your class `Test` should be a **public** class , Move `Test` to a own file, make it public and rerun your code.

Comment: Thank you it works problem is with its missing public modifier.

Answer (score 6):

Set it to the name of the field:

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(t,"te","teval");
```

[Documentation](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#setProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) here

Comment: already tried that and it gives this exception                  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'te' has no setter method

Comment: The test class is not public.  BeanUtils doesn't seem capable of parsing protected classes...(ps Otherwise it's right)

Answer (score 0):

The method signature of `setProperty()`

```
public static void setProperty(Object bean,
                               String name,
                               Object value)
                        throws IllegalAccessException,
                               InvocationTargetException

    Parameters:
        bean - Bean on which setting is to be performed
        name - Property name (can be nested/indexed/mapped/combo)
        value - Value to be set
```

**name is Property name "te" not "setTe".**

BeanUtils.setProperty(t,"te","teval");

Comment: I accept and tested but now it gives this error.I updated Question .Pls check.

Comment: @sunleo The test class is not public, see Jayamohan's answer, then apply Shawn and Pradeep's answers

Answer (score 0):

> The class must be **public**, and provide a public constructor that
>   accepts no arguments. This allows tools and applications to
>   dynamically create new instances of your bean, without necessarily
>   knowing what Java class name will be used ahead of time, like this:

```
     String className = ...;
     Class beanClass = Class.forName(className);
     Object beanInstance = beanClass.newInstance();
```

get from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#FAQ.property